# Why am I getting "no such file" in find results for files that exist?

Tags: bash, find

This is a minor issue, but it is a bit annoying.  I have looked and looked at this, but I cannot quite figure out why it is happening or how to stop it.  I have several thousand video files which I am slowly converting from MPEG II format to h.264 in MP4 containers for several reasons.  Each .mpg file has a .txt file and a .jpg file associated with it, and these files need to be changed from "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mpg.txt and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mpg.jpg to xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4.txt and xxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mp4.jpg, respectively, then the old .mpg files need to be deleted.  I use the following script named mpgscan.sh to do that very thing:

```
#! /bin/bash

suffix=".mpg"
mpegname="$@"
filename=${mpegname%"$suffix"}
mp4name="$filename"".mp4"
if [ -s "$mp4name" ]
then
    if lsof "$mp4name" > /dev/null || lsof "$mpegname" > /dev/null
    then
        echo "$filename in use"
    else
        if [[ -f "$mpegname"".txt" ]]
        then
            rename -f 's/\.mpg.txt$/.mp4.txt/' "$mpegname"".txt"
        fi
        if [[ -f "$mpegname"".jpg" ]] 
        then
            rename -f 's/\.mpg.jpg$/.mp4.jpg/' "$mpegname"".jpg"
        fi
        echo "$filename removed"
        rm "$mpegname"
    fi
fi
```

The conversion of the files is going on in the background, so every once in a while I update the associated files in a batch by entering the following command:

```
find /RAID/Recordings -name "*.mpg" -exec mpegscan.sh {} \;
```

It works pretty well, but instead of getting an expected output like:

```
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/K-9 (Recorded Tue Apr 01, 2008, HBOHD) removed
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kate & Leopold (Recorded Sat Sep 11, 2010, ENCR1H) removed
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kindergarten Cop (Recorded Tue May 06, 2008, HBOHD) removed
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/King Ralph (Recorded Wed Jul 16, 2008, HBOHD) in use
```

I get:

```
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/K-9 (Recorded Tue Apr 01, 2008, HBOHD) removed
find: '/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/K-9 (Recorded Tue Apr 01, 2008, HBOHD).mpg.jpg': No such file or directory
find: '/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/K-9 (Recorded Tue Apr 01, 2008, HBOHD).mpg.txt': No such file or directory
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kate & Leopold (Recorded Sat Sep 11, 2010, ENCR1H) removed
find: '/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kate & Leopold (Recorded Sat Sep 11, 2010, ENCR1H).mpg.jpg': No such file or directory
find: '/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kate & Leopold (Recorded Sat Sep 11, 2010, ENCR1H).mpg.txt': No such file or directory
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kindergarten Cop (Recorded Tue May 06, 2008, HBOHD) removed
find: '/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kindergarten Cop (Recorded Tue May 06, 2008, HBOHD).mpg.jpg': No such file or directory
find: '/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/Kindergarten Cop (Recorded Tue May 06, 2008, HBOHD).mpg.txt': No such file or directory
/RAID/Recordings/Movies/K/King Ralph (Recorded Wed Jul 16, 2008, HBOHD) in use
```

I have tried both the `rename` and `mv` commands with the same result.  I am flummoxed.  First of all, how / why is the error being reported by the `find` command?  The find command isn't issued against either the .jpg or .txt files, it is issued against .mpg files.  More to the point, why is there any sort of error at all?  The files being reported do exist and they are being properly processed by the mv / rename command.  Not only that, but I even check in the script to make sure they do exist before renaming them.  What am I missing?  The script runs perfectly with no errors if I run it manually against any .mpg file.

Comment: Note: you have minor flaw in your mpegscan.sh. The line `mpegname="$@"` accepts all command line arguments, not just first one. It will break on `mpegscan.sh 1.mpg 2.mpg` which will make it try fo look for file `"1.mpg 2.mpg.txt"` (with space). You might actually want to make mpegscan.sh to accept multiple arguments (which is quite easy) because with it you can change `\;` to `+` in your `find` invocation and make it collect more file names before sending them to `mpegscan.sh` which will help with race condition issue @frostschutz told you.

Comment: Proposed change (one liner because of SO comments limitations):
`suffix=".mpg"; while [ -n "$1" ]; do mpegname="$1";  shift;  .... rest of the script ...; done`
Invocation:
`find /RAID/Recordings -name "*.mpg" -exec mpegscan.sh {} +`

Comment: True, but since the find sends one file name with spaces as the argument, its not really an issue.  It also means I can send a filename with spaces and not have to worry about adding quotes around it.

Comment: As I mentioned, the find could send multiple arguments at once using `-exec ... {} +` syntax which is often beneficial (it always handle spaces correctly no matter what). Also I do not advise to rely on supplying filenames-with-spaces as unquoted arguments, it is against common practices and also could fail on double spaces (I know people who use multiple spaces in file name because it is easier to read for them).

Comment: I don't recommend it, either.  I did not create the files, or the filenames.  When I said "I", I meant the script.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`find` reads a list of directory entries and processes them one by one. For each entry that matches your conditions, it `-exec`utes your shell script.

Your script then renames files, thus changing the list of directory entries that `find` is still processing. So `find` still has filenames on its to-do list which you already removed/renamed.

When `find` tries to process them, it complains about the file no longer existing.

Example:

```
# create files in random order
$ shuf -e {a..z} {a..z}.foo {a..z}.bar | xargs touch

# rename using find -exec mv
$ busybox find -name "[a-z]" -exec mv {}.foo {}.baz \;
find: ./i.foo: No such file or directory
find: ./t.foo: No such file or directory
find: ./d.foo: No such file or directory
...
```

I'm using `busybox find` here because GNU findutils `find` is already smart enough to handle this case. You might be using an older version, or even the busybox variant if this is an embedded shell on some NAS of some kind.

You can ignore this error if the missing files would have been ignored by your conditions anyway; alternatively, let find build the list of files first and process this list afterwards.

Sometimes it's enough to use `find -print0 | xargs -0` pattern instead of `find -exec` pattern. It helps if your shellscript can process multiple arguments instead of just one.

Comment: Of course I could ignore the errors (tons of them)!  That is not the point.

Comment: No, it is not busybox or a NAS, nor is it older.  It is a server running Debian Bookworm - the latest release.  It is GNU findutils find 4.9.0, and apparently it isn't smart enough.  It's difficult to see what is going on - the non-errors, that is, with all the detritus in the way.

Comment: copy a small subset of your files someplace "safe" and do your testing there. It's too bad `find` doesn't have a `-vvv` options (superdebug).

Comment: `find` does have `-D all` or you could `strace` it. I did try with Debian Bookworm but unable to reproduce it. Is there something special about the filesystem? fuse or network mount perhaps? Sometimes these can trigger odd behavior as well.

Comment: @frostschutz : doah! `-D ...` (lots of fine grain options or `all`) is excellent! Tnx!

Comment: @LesRhorer Try the test provided as the example in the answer. I got the exact same behavior in my tests; My `find` version (4.8.0) doesn't produce those errors. If your `find` does output errors on those simple tests, then yes, the problem is in your `find` version.

Comment: The problem with the example in the answer is it will perform the process on all files it finds, which is emphatically NOT what I want.  I only want it to operate on cases where there is also a .mp4 file of the same name and where neither the .mpg file or the .mp4 are in use

Comment: I don't know how to comment on the release situation, since the release I am running is newer than the one referenced.  No, the mount is not particularly special.  It is not fuse or a network target.  It is a RAID array, but it is directly attached via the SATA bus.